# How do I convert 24 V from a car battery to 5 V @ 1A?

Tags: power-supply, power

I need to  make a phone charger using the batteries as source in my boat. Also i would also like to know the heat dissipation of the circuit as i need to use it for a minimum of 30 minutes.

Comment: You do like capital letter, don't you?

Comment: buy one - just google 24V to 5V buck converter

Comment: Why do you believe that the heat dissipation relates to how long you can run it for?

Comment: Use lots of diodes to step down the voltage ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that for using a marine power source, the device needs to be able to handle voltage spikes of *twice the nominal voltage* (48 Volt spikes) or even greater, as well as voltage reversals. The problem is similar to the automobile electronics case, just at possibly much higher voltages.

Comment: For 24v just buy a trucker's phone charger, most trucks are 24v nominal (2x 12v batteries) with the charging system behaving very similarly (~28v when running, potential for 48v spikes etc.). In fact most big boat engines are truck engines with a coat of blue paint & a huge price tag.

Answer (score 1):

Murata has the OKI-78SR-5 which is a 7V-36V in, 5V/1.5A out, switching regulator. $5 in quantity 1 from Digi-Key. Put it in an IP54 or better enclosure, and you're good!
These are highly efficient (90%), and thus don't generate much heat or waste much energy.
That is, at 5V/1A out, it's wasting <0.6W giving you 5W out.

Answer (score 1):

One option is a cheap DC-DC buck converter prebuilt module, such as those [available on eBay.com for under $2](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PC-LM2596-DC-DC-Step-Down-Adjustable-Converter-Power-Module-/330917982366?pt=US_Ham_Radio_Transmitters&hash=item4d0c3fb09e):

[image]

Add an inductor (e.g. 100 uH 1+ Amperes) and a 30+ Volt Zener diode or TVS before the input, to protect the module from spikes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6fbG1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Toroidal inductors like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-100uH-101-3A-AMP-Ring-Winding-Magnetic-Inductors-/110971908322?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item19d670f0e2) ($9.99 for 10) will serve the purpose, and if you have no other use for them, just put 6 or 7 in series on the input line, and the rest in series on the output line, for better spike management plus smoother output voltage.

[image: Inductor]